# No route found for "GET symfony 4

Tags: symfony

I create a blog controller and the routes in the controller and the templates that correspond to it. but  I get an error : No route found for "GET /blog/modifier/6". error
here is the function in the controller

note:it works in the backoffice

```
 /**
     * @Route("/modifier/{id}", name="modifier_posts", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function modifierpost(Request $request, Posts $post, $id): Response
    {

        $post= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Posts::class)->find($id);
        $em= $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $form = $this->createForm(PostType::class, $post);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em= $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('list_posts');
        }

        return $this->render('blog/modifierpost.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
           
        ]);
    }
```

and the modifierpost.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base-front.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
        <div class="col-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body"><br><br><br><br>
                       "><i class="mdi mdi-arrow-left"></i></a>Mettre à jour d'un post</h4><br>
                            <div class="form-group">
                            {{ form_start(form) }}
                            {{ form_widget(form) }}
                            {{ form_end(form) }}
                                <button class="text-danger" style="font-size: 14px;background:none; border:none;margin:0;padding:0;cursor: pointer;text-decoration: underline red;" class="btn" type="submit"><i class="mdi mdi-delete"></i></button>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
{% endblock %}
```

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEtkL.png)

Comment: It should be `@Route("/blog/modifier/{id}")` unless you already have `@Route("/blog")` at the top of your class..

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`ParamConverter`](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/best_practices/controllers.html#using-the-paramconverter). Make sure that you have a `Post` with the `id` equals to `6`. And make sure that you have `@Route("/blog")` at the top of your controller class

```php
/**
 * @Route("/modifier/{id}", name="modifier_posts", methods={"GET","POST"})
 **/
public function modifierpost(Request $request, Posts $post): Response
{
  $form = $this->createForm(PostType::class, $post);
  $form->handleRequest($request);

  if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
    return $this->redirectToRoute('list_posts');
  }

  return $this->render('blog/modifierpost.html.twig', [
    'form' => $form->createView()       
  ]);
}
```

Comment: I have a post with id 6 but i dont know how to use paramConverter  i guess you mean i add an annotation in the controller              @ParamConverter("post", class="Posts:Post"

Comment: No you just have to copy / paste the code above and it will works. ParamConverter is normally automatically active